# mysql query to fetch the data of within and near paritcular latitude and longitude

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying this query but its giving me only near by distance. 
For example `pune latitude=18.52043` and  `longitude =73.85674`.
It is showing me nearest location and its fine.
Problem is that, if user search for india country then it should fetch all latitude and longitude of india country.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

```
SELECT    
(

 6373 *
        acos(
            cos( radians(18.52043) ) *
            cos( radians( `latitude` ) ) *
            cos(
                radians( `longitude` ) - radians(73.85674)
            ) +
            sin(radians(18.52043)) *
            sin(radians(`latitude`))
        )
    ) `distance`
FROM
    `caw_user_meal`
HAVING
    `distance` < 50
ORDER BY
    `distance`
```

Comment: @Trupti  if i dont add  HAVING  distance < 50 then it shows all distance.

Comment: i want to build search query like https://www.airbnb.co.in/s/Pune?source=bb&ss_id=gpnvyz99 do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first determine all the boundary lat long of all countries in the world. You can download that data free from here [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/)

After that you have to check if a given lat long falls within the boundary of a particular country.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Click on this [link](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=424206#rows:id=1), Search (Ctl + F) for India an you will see a bunch of coordinates in JSON_4236 column. Insert them into your database with a table having one attribute as India. Run the above query with a WHERE Clause

```
SELECT    
(

 6373 *
        acos(
            cos( radians(18.52043) ) *
            cos( radians( `latitude` ) ) *
            cos(
                radians( `longitude` ) - radians(73.85674)
            ) +
            sin(radians(18.52043)) *
            sin(radians(`latitude`))
        )
    ) `distance`
FROM
    `caw_user_meal`
WHERE
    `country` = India
```